# Is there a simple way to customize IdentityServer4's configuration and operational dababase mapping?

Tags: identityserver4

I'm implementing an authentication server using IS4 with an Oracle database to store the configuration and operational data.

As far as I know, Oracle has a limitation of 30 characters for tables and columns names. Because of that, some of IS4's properties causes errors when applying the database migrations, such as:

- AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken
- FrontChannelLogoutSessionRequired
- BackChannelLogoutSessionRequired
- UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh

In order to override the default database mapping I've:

1 - made a copy of the original ConfigurationDbContext:

```
public class CustomConfigurationDbContext : CustomConfigurationDbContext<CustomConfigurationDbContext>
{
    public CustomConfigurationDbContext(DbContextOptions<CustomConfigurationDbContext> options, ConfigurationStoreOptions storeOptions) : base(options, storeOptions){}
}

public class CustomConfigurationDbContext<TContext> : DbContext, IConfigurationDbContext
    where TContext : DbContext, IConfigurationDbContext
{
    private readonly ConfigurationStoreOptions storeOptions;

    public CustomConfigurationDbContext(DbContextOptions<TContext> options, ConfigurationStoreOptions storeOptions)
        : base(options)
    {
        this.storeOptions = storeOptions ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(storeOptions));
    }

    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IdentityResource> IdentityResources { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApiResource> ApiResources { get; set; }

    public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        return base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(storeOptions.DefaultSchema);

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ClientEntityTypeConfiguration());
    }

    private class ClientEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Client>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Client> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(p => p.AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken).HasColumnName("ALWAYS_INC_USR_CLAIM_IN_TKN");

            builder.Property(p => p.FrontChannelLogoutSessionRequired).HasColumnName("FRONT_LOGOUT_SESSION_REQ");

            builder.Property(p => p.BackChannelLogoutSessionRequired).HasColumnName("BACK_LOGOUT_SESSION_REQ");

            builder.Property(p => p.UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh).HasColumnName("UP_ACCESS_TKN_CLAIM_ON_REFRESH");
        }
    }
}
```

2 - changed the Startup.cs:

```
var builder = services
    .AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        ...
    })
    .AddConfigurationStore<CustomConfigurationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
            b.UseOracle(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Auth2Connection"), sql =>
                sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)
                   .MigrationsHistoryTable(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppMigrationTable"), Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppSchema")));

        options.DefaultSchema = Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppSchema");
    })
```

It have actually worked, but I wonder if is there an official or simpler way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've done it in the correct way as there is no out of the box option to control the column name mapping since [it is hardcoded](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage/blob/dev/src/Extensions/ModelBuilderExtensions.cs).

There only exists an option to control the tablename mapping:

```
var builder = services
    .AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        ...
    })
    .AddConfigurationStore<CustomConfigurationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        ...    
        options.ApiResource = new TableConfiguration("MyTableName", "MySchemaName");
    })
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of this "options.ApiResource" configuration. It comes in handy and probably saved me a lot of time! Thank you!